# Two instances of ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

Is there a way to create two instances of ObjectMapper for different purpose.

**Modified ObjectMapper**

```
    @Component
    class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{
      public MyObjectMapper(){
        super();
      }

    public MyObjectMapper(MyObjectMapper om) {
        super(om);
     }

    @Override
    public MyObjectMapper copy() {
        return new MyObjectMapper(this);
     }
   }
```

Now use it as follows

```
@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper; //performs standard serialization
@Autowire MyObjectMapper myMapper; //i can add custom filters in thiis mapper.
```

I tried a similar setup but the custom mapper actually affects the original mapper all the `rest controllers` throw `JSON parse error: Unrecognized field`

**Edit:** Not sure if this point is very important but still adding it
Am using `spring-boot-starter-json`

Comment: "_the custom mapper actually affects the original mapper_" did you actually define two `ObjectMapper` components, or is the mapper from snippet the only component you have?

Comment: The Mapper is the only component I have. The reason is , adding filter to Autowired ObjectMapper, permanently applies the changes. But I need special serialization in only certain places. I can do a "new" whenever required, but am looking for something clean

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. As far as I see, if this is the only config you have related to `ObjectMapper`, then `@Autowired ObjectMapper` and `@Autowired MyObjectMapper` are the exact same bean. You need to declare two component beans: one for "clean" mapper, and the other bean for customized mapper. Since they both autowire candidates then you need to qualify both and declare which one you're trying to autowire (or primarize one of them). Just like you did in your answer.

Comment: @Prokhorov First thing MyObjectMapper and ObjectMapper are not exactly same beans. The thing which makes it same is the 'new ObjectMapper()' which you are calling and this is because , I use an automated 'Spring Boot Starter Json". This can become less ambiguous if you use standard jackson and '@Bean' it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Combining with Answer from [Aniket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099347/aniket-sahrawat) figured out what is wrong and still looking for some more explanation.

Instead of instantiating the ObjectMapper as `new ObjectMapper()`. Building it with `Mapper` fixed it.

So, two have multiple instance of ObjectMapper

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
   return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .build();
}

@Bean("customMapper")
public ObjectMapper customMapper(){
  ObjectMapper customMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build();
     mapper.<your customization , filters, providers etc;>
     return mapper;
}
```

The `@Primary` will be used by in all default cases i.e When you simply `@Autowire` or the default serialization applied to your Response/Request Body by your controller.

To use your Custom Mapper, explicitly use with the Bean ID.

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("customMapper") ObjectMapper mapper;
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what was suggested in the above answer? Also, you don't need `@Primary` if you inject the `ObjectMapper` as `ObjectMapper objectMapper`.

Comment: @Somebody Read all the comments in that answer .

Comment: And @Primary is mandatory if you are using 'spring-boot-starter-json'

Answer (score 2):

And that's exactly where you should use [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation.

> This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for candidate beans when autowiring. It may also be used to annotate other custom annotations that can then in turn be used as qualifiers.

Comment: And now this actually questions my spring knowledge. Does spring consider MyCustomMapper and ObjectMapper as same bean? Why does it affect my overall serialization ? . MyCustomMapper might extend ObjectMapper at the same time it can implement may other interfaces qualifying it as a separate bean together

Comment: [Here is an example](https://pastebin.com/azqZt8Jk) of what I suspect is wrong in your case. First run the program *as is*, then uncomment the part where its written *Uncomment the below* and run again. For more control on it, I suggested using `Qualifier`. It's your choice afterall :)

Comment: tried qualifier. Declared two bean with one as '@Primary' and one with a Bean ID. and used the modified ObjectMapper with a '@Qualifier'. And again, it messes up the actual implicit jackson used by Spring for all the controller. Commenting the modified '@bean' in the configuration fixes the problem

Comment: The example you shared wont work. just extending the ObjectMapper will throw 'does not override copy()' error